# TDD The Odin Project

Tags: javascript

Buenas noches amigo de stackOverflow tengo una consulta que hacerles, sucede que aún sigo en mis practicas con la plataforma de aprendizaje **The Odin Project** y en la actualidad estoy introduciéndome en el desarrollo basado en prueba **TDD** en el segundo ejercicio que esta reposando en el github de la plataforma expone una serie de pruebas en el ejercicio antes mencionado y en el primer ejercicio de **repeatString** [https://github.com/TheOdinProject/javascript-exercises/tree/solutions/repeatString][1] me vi forzado a urgar en la rama de **soluciones** donde dan la solución correcta a lo que piden y es que no me queda claro que este codigo:

```
const repeatString = function(word, times) {
  if (times < 0) return 'ERROR';
  let string = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    string += word;
  }
  return string;
};

module.exports = repeatString;
```

según al ejecutar la prueba me de como resultado:

```
> javascript-exercises@1.0.0 test
> jest "repeatString.spec.js"

Debugger attached.
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
 PASS  02_repeatString/repeatString.spec.js
  repeatString
    ✓ repeats the string (11 ms)
    ○ skipped repeats the string many times
    ○ skipped repeats the string 1 times
    ○ skipped repeats the string 0 times
    ○ skipped returns ERROR with negative numbers
    ○ skipped repeats the string a random amount of times
    ○ skipped works with blank strings

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       6 skipped, 1 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.772 s
Ran all test suites matching /repeatString.spec.js/i.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

cuando el **README.md** muy explicito dice:

> Escriba una función que simplemente repita la cadena un número dado de veces:

> repeatString ( 'hey' ,  3 )  // devuelve 'heyheyhey'
> Notará en este ejercicio que hay múltiples pruebas (ver en el archivo
> repeatString.spec.js). Solo la primera prueba está habilitada
> actualmente. Entonces, después de asegurarse de que este primero pase,
> habilite los demás uno por uno eliminando el .skipde la
> test.skip()función.
>
> Sugerencias Tome nota de la llamada de función anterior: ¿cómo se
> llama exactamente?
>
> Vas a querer usar un bucle para este.
>
> Cree una variable para contener la cadena que va a devolver, cree un
> bucle que se repita la cantidad de veces dada y agregue la cadena dada
> al resultado de cada bucle.
>
> Si la ejecución npm test repeatString.spec.jsdevuelve resultados
> similares a los siguientes:
>
> Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total Tests:       6 skipped, 1 passed, 7
> total Asegúrese de haber habilitado el resto de las pruebas (ver
> arriba).

En mi lógica fácil esta crear un bucle for de la siguiente manera:

```
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  text += "hey";
}
```

y claro que este me desvuelve **heyheyhey** en 3 ocasiones tal como pide el ejercicio pero al incluirlo en la variable **repeatString** de la siguiente manera

```
const repeatString = function() {
    let text = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      text += "hey";
    }
    return text
};
repeatString()

// Do not edit below this line
module.exports = repeatString;
```

Este me da error, no entiendo por favor alguien que pueda ayudarme a entender que puede estar mal en lo que estoy haciendo y gracias por adelantado. Un saludo

Comment: *Entonces, después de asegurarse de que este primero pase, **habilite los demás uno por uno eliminando el .skip** de la test.skip()función.*. Ya eliminaste los `.skip()` del archivo `repeatString.spec.js`?

Comment: este no es el caso amiguito, el caso era que no podía hacer que el test me aceptara mi código pero creo que ya lo he solucionado.